# xcode error: linker command failed with exit code 1 googletoolboxmac

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

> ld: warning: directory not found for option
>   '-F/Users/nicksfikas/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Tic_Toe-alfdrybbuuvwxqfdmqfxrrljmyli/Build/Intermediates.noindex/SwiftMigration/Tic
>   Toe/Products/Debug-iphoneos/GoogleToolboxForMac' ld: framework not
>   found GoogleToolboxForMac clang: error: linker command failed with
>   exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

what should I do?

Comment: you have a pod file in your project ?

Answer (score 1):

This is because a 3rd party library is missing from your system..

**try**

I encountered the same problem and my solution is as follow:

Close the current project in xcode ---> Go to your project file and open the project by clicking the .xcworkspace file. Note: not the .xodeproj file.

**or**

You can clean the project in Product Tab and select clean. To build select build in product tab in Xcode.

hope it works.. :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you installed a pod file and you are still trying to build from the .xcodeproj file instead of .xcworkspace